# Piano just moved 2 miles seems to have middle on permanentl

Tags: piano

I just had a piano moved 2 miles to my home. The middle pedal compresses very easily, and the piano plays softly as though middle pedal is permanently used. Also, D and Dflat below middle C won’t play. Can you help me know what to do?

Comment: Have a piano tech look at it? What kind of piano is it, grand, upright?

Comment: & once you've got a quote from the piano tech, send it to the removal company. They broke it, they fix it.

Comment: @ToddWilcox - I guess it's UK, with a practice pedal, on an upright studio, (more common here) but because we have this 'don't want to tell you anything' profile option, it ain't easy.

Comment: Can you open the piano and have a look? Maybe take some pictures?

Answer (score 2):

The practice pedal often has a rod which is between pedal and curtain, probably become dislodged. Wouldn't mind betting it's landed by those two errant notes!